# Javascript plugins do not bundle order wise in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to bundle my JS files through Webpack (version 5.x) but it is not bundling order-wise. Here is my configuration file:

```
const path = require("path");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: [
    "./src/assets/js/plugins/jQuery.js",
    "./src/assets/js/plugins/mdb.js",
    "./src/assets/js/plugins/aos.js",
    "./src/assets/js/main.js",
  ],
  output: {
    filename: "assets/js/[name].[contenthash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ 
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),
  ]
};
```

I am expecting in the bundle file orderwise like `jQuery.js`, `mdb.js`, `aos.js` and `main.js` that I added in the `entry`. Please help me find the issue and a better way to buddle the JS files.

Thank You